# How do I get my Canon MX420 printer working?

Tags: printing, canon, scanning

I was using Canon MX420 printer properly until I upgrade my ubuntu to 11.10 . After that I can add it to my printers but I can't print or scan any page !
What should I do now ?

*sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-mx420series*

```
:Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  python-hachoir-parser nautilus-actions iat nautilus-image-converter
  pyrenamer nautilus-filename-repairer python-hachoir-metadata
  python-hachoir-core md5deep
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  cnijfilter-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cnijfilter-common cnijfilter-mx420series
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 294 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,783 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7,688 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu/ oneiric/main cnijfilter-common amd64 3.50-2ubuntu4 [113 kB]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu/ oneiric/main cnijfilter-mx420series amd64 3.50-2ubuntu4 [1,670 kB]
Fetched 1,783 kB in 17s (100 kB/s)                                             
Selecting previously deselected package cnijfilter-common.
(Reading database ... 262781 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking cnijfilter-common (from .../cnijfilter-common_3.50-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package cnijfilter-mx420series.
Unpacking cnijfilter-mx420series (from .../cnijfilter-mx420series_3.50-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Setting up cnijfilter-common (3.50-2ubuntu4) ...
Setting up cnijfilter-mx420series (3.50-2ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
```

Comment: I know this might not help as I am new as well,but my dad has that same printer on a desktop.we hooked it physically to computer,clicked gear in upper right corner,clicked printer,add printer then just selected a driver.thenwhen it prompted to print test page we did and were successful

Comment: if you do a #dpkg -L cnijfilter-mx420series  does the PPD file exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original source : http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2011/06/download-install-canon-printer-driver.html

Type the following command in terminal (Cntrl-Alt-T)

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-mx420series

All the best.

In case of any error please post it here.

---

Edited

to configure the printer you can use lpadmin

1. Restart the CUPS daemon by typing

   > sudo /etc/init.d/cups restart
   >   OR sudo service cups restart
2. Register the printer to the spooler by typing

> for usb = /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p [printer_name] -m [PPD_filename] -v cnijusb:/[USB_port] -E

like

> sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p MX420USB -m canonmx420.ppd -v cnijusb:/dev/usb/lp0 -E

for LAN
For a LAN connection

like

/usr/sbin/lpadmin -p [printer_name] -m [PPD_filename] -v cnijnet:/[MAC_address] -E

> sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p MX420LAN -m canonmx420.ppd -v cnijnet:/00-00-85-AB-C1-23 -E

3.Set the default printer

/usr/sbin/lpadmin -d [printer_name]  like

> sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -d MX420USB

4.unblacklist usblp module by typing

> sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-cups-usblp.conf
>   Add a # in front of the line with "blacklist usblp" - Note this might cause problems where you are running multiple printers from the same system where CUPS manages those printers directly

5.check the printer status by typing

cngpijmonmx420 [printer_name] like

> cngpijmonmx420 MX420USB

if there is no error,then your printer is ready....... if error we can resolve it...

Comment: Thanks ! There is an error :"E: Unable to locate package cnijfilter-mx420series"

Comment: E: Unable to locate package cnijfilter-mx420series :- you will get this error if that package is not added to your package list or it is not existing.make sure you added the repository and updated your package list.. You should not copy and paste all the above command at once but one by one you have to do it. when you do that you will get some directions and instructions. you will get it right.

Comment: Yes ! I disabled it ! Now I enabale it and the answer is in the main post .

Comment: well done! you have installed your printer driver. check the list of printers and find  if it is added to printers. if yes Print a test page. if no add it and print the test page.

Comment: Sorry ! But I can't find it now!!!I don't know why because I added it some days ago ! I think the problem is that it connected via wifi not wire !

Comment: ok. after installation, the printer won't be added..... so you have to add it by doing the steps mentioned in my answer (under Edited Tab).....

Comment: if it is the problem of wifi I don't know.... but it has to work since mac address is sam

Comment: I found the answer ! I should set it up to connect to my wireless network ! Thanks a lot to rjkrocks !