# How do I get my Canon MX420 printer running?

Tags: canon

I followed the answer given to same question I'm asking, but get stuck at the point shown
below.

Answer I used came from here:
[How do I get my Canon MX420 printer working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97869/how-do-i-get-my-canon-mx420-printer-working)

Point where I ran into a problem:

```
aa@aa-laptop:~$ sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p MX420USB -m canonmx420.ppd -v cnijusb:/dev/usb/lp0 -E
lpadmin: Unable to copy PPD file!
```

Thanks,
Brian